# SDL: responding to SDL_Quit, Esc with SDLmain.lib

Tags: c++, sdl

I want to use SDL with SDLmain.lib (because I'm designing something for a class, so it needs to be simple).

When I click the X on the display window (as opposed to console window, if I have one), the program doesn't end.  It also doesn't end when I hit Escape, which would be nice.  Finally, when I try to Show the Desktop in Windows, if an SDL program is running, nothing happens.  (I include this in case it's related.)

If I weren't using SDLmain, I'd edit WndProc.  Come to think of it, SDLmain surely should have WndProc? but doesn't.  What can I do to tell SDL to respond to these messages?  I can SDL_PollEvent in main, but a) that would mean I'd have to have an event-checking loop in main, which isn't always suitable, and b) I'm not sure how I'd tell it to listen for clicking the X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example for a simple [event](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.fcg) function

```
SDL_Event event ;

while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
{
    switch( event.type )       
    {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            running = FALSE ;  //set you variable that controls the main flow of the program to false
            break;

        default:
            break ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call one of the event pumping functions to make SDL pump the window's message queue. This has to be done on the thread that created the window.

When you try to close the window via the X, an event is queued to SDL's event queue (`SDL_QUIT`, I think).

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't have any effect.  You're right about it being an SDL_QUIT message.

Comment: Try pasting some example code. You need to call one of SDL's event functions (or just `SDL_PumpMessages`, which most of them call) in a loop.

Comment: OK...I'm not sure it will be helpful.  Here's the program.  Can't force line breaks in the comment here, it seems. 
 
`int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
 cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;

 system ("pause"); 

 return 0;
}`